# Why we cant solve $y''+y\sin(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''+y\sin(x)=0$$

I tried to do it in series method but cannot reach an analytic solution, is there a proof that we cannot solve this kind of functions analytically, by the way is there a name for this kind of equations?

Comment: Seems that with a substitution you can turn it into a Mathieu function: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function).

Comment: Look at Sturm–Liouville equations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory

Comment: Right, if you make the substitution $x \rightarrow 2r+\frac{\pi}{2}$, you get the Mathieu equation $\frac{d^2 y}{d r^2} + \left[a - 2 q \right] y = 0$, with $a = 0$ and $q = -2$. The general solution is then $c_1 \mathrm{C}\left(0,-2, \frac{x}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \right) + c_2 \mathrm{S}\left(0,-2, \frac{x}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \right) $, where $\mathrm{C}\left(a, q, r \right)$ and $\mathrm{S}\left(a, q, r \right)$ are the Mathieu cosine and sine, respectively.